# Take In File Delete One Line From That File And Create A New File?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a text document that has a list of names in it, each one on its own line. I want to be able to go through that file, and delete one particular name. So I'm trying to create an array with all the original names, have a loop go through that array and add all the names except the one that needs to be deleted to a new array. If I try to print the new array, it still contains all of the names including the one that needs to be deleted.

```
   $Delete = "Pete";
   $startingNames = file("names.txt");
   $newNames = array();
   foreach($startingNames as $name)
   {
      if(strpos($name, $Delete) == false) //If its not the one that needs to be deleted
      {
         $newNames[] = $name; //Add it to the new array.
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, strpos will return 0, which will be interpreted as `false`. Instead, we need to use the triple-equals operator to confirm the type as well as the value.

```
strpos($name, $Delete) === false
```

This would also be a good time to use `array_filter`. This function will allow you to run a 'filter function' over an array, creating a new array with only the values you want. For example:

```
<?php

$names = ['Dave', 'Pete', 'Alex', 'Mark'];
$delete = 'Mark';
$newNames = array_filter($names, function ($name) use ($delete) {
  return strpos($name, $delete) === false;
});

print_r($newNames);
```